# Jquery ui slider tabs cannot set the property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-tabs

Slider tabs have extra space at the bottom between navigators and content.
I am also trying to make the page responsive but when i resize the window, the content size remains the same so i have to open new window at the required size and then open the website ... here is the i am using for tabs ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tabs = $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs({
       autoplay: false,
       indicators: true,
       panelArrows: true,
       panelArrowsShowOnHover: false,
       tabsLoop:true,
       tabsAnimSpeed: 800,
       responsive:true,
       tabsScroll:false,
    });

});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

May be it help

```
var slider = function () {
   $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs({
     autoplay: false,
     indicators: true,
     panelArrows: true,
     panelArrowsShowOnHover: false,
     tabsLoop:true,
     tabsAnimSpeed: 800,
     responsive:true,
     tabsScroll:false,
   });
}

// when browser window change size
$(window).resize(function () {
   slider()
 });


 $(document).ready(function(){
   slider()
 });
```

Comment: No, it still is same as before